# When should literal classes be used in C++?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constexpr

Can someone tell me when are *literal classes* needed in *C++*?
I am getting a little confused from *constexpr* constructors, constexpr members, and I can't see what the point is. I'd like to see some practical use of it.

Also I'd want to know if a *set* member function needs to be *constexpr*, i.e.:

```
constexpr void set_num(int a) { num = a; }
```

Comment: You can't modify a compile-time object.

Comment: @VaughnCato I'd like to know which part of my question are you referring to. Thanks

Comment: It appeared that your `set_num` member was trying to modify a member of a class.  If `set_num` is declared constexpr, then the object can't be modified, so your assignment wouldn't be valid.

Comment: I haven't come across a particular case where I would use constexpr instances of classes, but I don't use constexprs much anyway.  In principle, you would create a class when you want to group several related constexpr values and functions together.

Comment: So they might have a better runtime performance I guess? When declared as literal classes the overhead of calling the constructor is removed. You might want to write it as an answer. I guess I got the essence.

Comment: @VaughnCato, you're right that a `constexpr` member function can't modify the object, but that's like any other `const` member function, not because the object is a "compile-time object". You can have mutable objects of literal types.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Not sure what you mean by a "literal type".

Comment: @VaughnCato, The topic of the question is _literal classes_ which are _literal types_ that are also _class types_.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: True, but I was thinking that was just a misnomer, and that the OP was actually talking about using constexpr objects of class type, but I don't know how to interpret "mutable object of literal types" in that way.  I'm don't believe you can have a mutable constexpr object.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Ok, I think I understand.  I did a little digging and found that a "literal type" in the standard is basically a type where it is possible to create a constexpr object of that type, but you can also create non-constexpr objects of that type, so your statement makes sense.  Also, I agree that it is the fact that constexpr implies const which makes the assignment invalid, so the point is well taken.

Comment: Right, like I said in my answer below: That doesn't mean all objects of that type _must_ be `constexpr` constants, it just means that objects of that type _can_ be declared as `constexpr` constants

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++03 this object has *dynamic initialization*

```
struct Data {
  int i;
  int j;
};
Data init_data();  // calculate something
const Data data = init_data();
```

i.e. when the program starts, before `main` runs, the function will be called and the object gets initialized.

In C++11 the object can have *constant initialization*, a form of *static initialization*, meaning that its value is set at compile-time and it's initialized before the program begins. This is useful to avoid the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) among other things.  To ensure the type gets *constant initialization* it must be initialized by a constant expression, so must have a `constexpr` constructor and any functions called in the full expression must be `constexpr` functions.

The type `Data` is trivial so its implicitly-declared constructors are `constexpr` constructors, so to make the global `data` undergo *constant initialization* we just need to make `init_data()` be a `constexpr` function:

```
struct Data {
  int i;
  int j;
};
constexpr Data init_data();  // calculate something
constexpr Data data = init_data();
```

The advantage of a *literal type* is that such types can be used in other constant expressions i.e. in contexts that require compile-time constants.  So now that we have our `data` object as a compile-time constant, we can use it in other constant expressions e.g. to initialize other compile-time constants:

```
const int i = ::data.i;
```

And we can use the `Data` type for a static data member with an in-class initializer:

```
struct MoreData {
  static constexpr Data zerozero = Data{};  // OK, Data is a literal type
};
```

If `Data` wasn't a literal type we would have to write:

```
struct MoreData {
  static const Data zerozero;
};

// in moredata.cc
const Data MoreData::zerozero = Data{};
```

And then code which only sees the header doesn't know the value of `MoreData::zerozero` and can't use it in compile-time optimisations.

So the advantage of the "literal type" rules is that they allow you to define new class types that can be used in constant expressions. In C++03 only very few types, such as integers, could be used in constant expressions, e.g. integer literals such as `1` or `0x23` or compile-time constants of integer type.  In C++11 you can write you own types which can have moderately complicated logic in their constructors (anything that can be expressed in a `constexpr` function) but can still be used as a compile-time constant.

> Also I'd want to know if a set member function needs to be constexpr, i.e.

A `constexpr` member function is a special case of a `const` member function, so it can't modify (non`-mutable`) members of the type.  A setter function, which modifies the object, can't be const.

To be a literal type a class must follow some rules including having at least one `constexpr` constructor. That doesn't mean all objects of that type *must* be `constexpr` constants, it just means that objects of that type *can* be `constexpr` constants if they are declared as such and are initialized using one of the class' `constexpr` constructors.  To use the `Data` example again, most objects in your program would not be constants:

```
Data d = { 0, 1 };
d.i = d.i + 5;
```

So if you added a setter, a function which modifies the object, then it would only make sense to use it on non-const objects of that type, and like any other functions which modifies the type it should not be

Answer (score 8):

constexpr fixes a problem in C++98 when using numeric limits. Before C++11 an expression such as

```
std::numeric_limits<short>::max()
```

can not be used as integral constant, although it is almost equal to macro `INT_MAX`. with C++11, such an expression is declared as constexpr so that, for example,
you can use it to declare **arrays** or in **compile-time computations (metaprogramming)**:

```
std::array<float,std::numeric_limits<short>::max()> a;
```

Comment: While indeed `constexpr` in everyday use makes the most sense for such constant return functions, this is of course only half the truth about `constexpr` and its usage and implications (and only half an answer to the actual question).

Answer (score 3):

A big advantage of `constexpr` classes is that they may be put into .ro data which can lead to executable size reductions and performance boosts. Esp. for geometric types e.g. or similar 'simple' types this is very neat as you could also get rid of "magic" numbers. See e.g. https://www.kdab.com/kdab-contributions-to-qt-5-0-part-4/.